# Change The Tab Name Of An App Using The Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

consulting the Facebook documentation on: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

I saw that is possible change the tab name of an app using the graph, with an HTML POST like this:

**Request URL**:https://graph.facebook.com/128003037303086/tabs?app_id=333139666735547&custom_name=TestName&access_token=AAADneKiiFaMBAKKsAFDs9RIHaEvZB1zV7jZAMKEMeUT86J2XOhlZBg28ew6s8pZA5PZBCmBjmZBcAyptQaqFEhs47phpwSsGU4KQCxJPFq6SxWWDXVbTA3G8fhAqIO8mkZD

**Request Method**:POST

**Status Code**:200 OK

I am receiving an ok response but the problem is that the tab name is not changing.

What is wrong???

P.S: I am using the JS SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this,

https://graph.facebook.com/128003037303086/tabs/app_333139666735547?custom_name=TestName

is fine.